# Change linux shell

Tags: linux, centos7, shell, terminal-server, terminal

On my Centos7 Server I have different shells for my users.

For example the terminal as root looks like:

`[root@hostname www]#`.

The terminal as a different user looks like `bash-4.2$`.

If I type `echo $0` to get the currently-used shell, I get `/bin/bash` on my different user and `-bash` on my root.

Do I have to configure the shell for my different user, in order to make it look like the shell for my root?

Is there a way to use the shell used in Debian (`bash`) to see the full path of my location? (`root@server:/var/www#` instead of `root@server www`).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not the shell (which is always Bash), that's the command prompt format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your user is missing the skeleton files, the default `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` etc. which are normally copied into a user's home directory from `/etc/skel` when a user is created. You can copy these files yourself if they are missing or corrupted.

Comment: Well that seems to work. I just copied the .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_logout from my root user, because I dont find a /etc/skel folder on my Centos-Server. The .bash_history was already in the home folder. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MrWaffelXD The `/etc/skel` directory itself is provided by the `filesystem` package, which every CentOS system has installed. The `.bash*` files within it are provided by the `bash` package. It sounds like someone has manually deleted these files. Try restoring them with `yum reinstall filesystem bash`.

Comment: Somehow I messed something up in the past. I reinstalled it and have the /etc/skel folder now. That should be the issue for the missing files in the home directory I guess. Thanks again ^.^

Answer (score 1):

A user's prompt is determined by the value of the shell variables PS1, PS2, PS3, PS4.

```
PS1 – The value of this parameter is expanded and used as the primary prompt string. 
      The default value for Bash is \s-\v\$ .
PS2 – The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used as the secondary 
      prompt string. The default value for Bash is >
PS3 – The value of this parameter is used as the prompt for the select command
PS4 – The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and the value is printed 
      before each command bash displays during an execution trace.
```

Typically a user only customizes PS1.

Bash allows these variables to be customized by inserting one or more escaped special characters:

```
\a : ASCII bell character
\d : The date in “Weekday Month Date” format (e.g., “Tue May 26”)
\D{format} : the format is passed to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into
the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. 
The braces are required
\e : Tne ASCII escape character
\h : The hostname up to the first ‘.’
\H : The full hostname
\j : The number of jobs currently managed by the shell
\l : The basename of the shell's terminal device name
\n : A newline
\s : The name of the shell
\t : The current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
\T : The current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
\@ : The current time in 12-hour am/pm format
\A : The current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
\u : The username of the current user
\v : The current version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
\V : The current release of bash, version and patch level (e.g., 4.12.0)
\w : The current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\W : The basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated 
     with a tilde
\! : The history number of this command
\# : The command number of this command
\$ : If the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
\nnn : The character corresponding to the octal number nnn
\\ : A backslash
\[ : Begin sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed 
     a terminal control sequence into the prompt
\] : End sequence of non-printing characters
```

Example:

```
fpm@fpmurphy ~]$ PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ "
[Sun Jul 05 23:44:17 fpm@fpmurphy:~ ] $
```

To persist the custom prompt across a reboot or a logout, add the prompt to the users `$HOME/.bashrc`, or to make it the default prompt for all users, add it to `/etc/bashrc` or create an entry under `/etc/bashrc.d` depending on your distribution.